# Python LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: platform not found khr

Tags: ubuntu, pyopencl

While making nosetests for the set of Python programs in Ubuntu an error occurs:

```
devices = [ d for d in cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices() if
LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: platform not found khr


File "/home/fateeva/prog/deflectometry/SGMFMeasurement/_PhaseShifts.py", line 30, in <module>
    devices = [ d for d in cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices() if
LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: platform not found khr
```

How it's possible to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have pyopencl installed but none of the actual device drivers. Please consult the documentation at https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html.

Here is the description of such a behaviour:

> Note that PyOpenCL is no fun (i.e. cannot run code) without an OpenCL device driver (a so-called “ICD”, for “installable client driver”) that provides access to hardware through OpenCL. If you get an error message like pyopencl.cffi_cl.LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: , that means you have no OpenCL drivers installed.

Basically, the next command should be enough to get it running on a CPU:

```
[pip]conda install pocl
```

For proper installation of AMD and Nvidia devices look for vendor supplied OpenCL drivers.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$ sudo apt install pocl-opencl-icd
```

I tested it on Ubuntu WSL for Windows 10, Python 3.8.10.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
sudo nvidia-smi
```

or run it (without sudo) as root.

After that your should be able to run it.

Add

```
nvidia-smi
```

to /etc/rc.local (before exit, of course), so you GPU will be available after each boot.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because OpenCL drivers arent properly installed.

Intel CPUs require OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors (16.1.1 or later). Download and install OpenCL™ Runtime latest from intel website. Ignore the compatibility warning.

Source: https://youtu.be/AieYqNQ6ADM

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

```
pip install pocl-binary-distribution
```

might work. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your python script as root. If `cl.get_platforms()` does not throw any errors under root, then your user does not have sufficient privilege to perform the action. To solve this, install `nvidia-modprobe` package:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

[Source](http://blog.linux4us.org/2015/05/30/how-to-solve-pyopencl-clgetplatformids-failed/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It should work:

```
devices = [ d for d in cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices(cl.device_type.GPU)]
```

If you want to list all the compatible devices on your platform just use

```
platform = cl.get_platform()
my_devices = platform[0].get_devices(device_type = cl.devices_type.ALL)
print my_devices
```

To create a context on any compatible device use this:

```
context = cl.Context([my_devices[<index>])
```

Where  corresponds to the device for which you want to create a context. for example:

```
context = cl.Context([my_devices[0])
```

also refer to this post of mine, it will help. I too had problems with this:

[pyopencl: creating context for specific device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995859/error-pyopencl-creating-context-for-specific-device/13001328#13001328)

Comment: It's the call to cl.get_platforms() that's failing, so none of the code in this answer will work.