# ERROR: pyopencl: creating context for specific device

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I want to create context for specific device on my platform. But I am getting an error.

Code:

```
import pyopencl as cl
platform = cl.get_platforms()
devices = platform[0].get_devices(cl.device_type.GPU)
ctx = cl.Context(devices[0])
```

The error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Programs_OpenCL_Python\Matrix Multiplication\3\main3.py", line 16, in <module>
    ctx = cl.Context(devices[0])
AttributeError: 'Device' object has no attribute '__iter__'
```

The program compiles and executes without any errors and warnings if i use:

```
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
```

But I will have to manually select the device type every-time I execute the program using this function.
I can set the following environmental variable

```
PYOPENCL_CTX='0'
```

Using this I will not be able to create contexts for different devices available based on the requirement. It will be by default set to device 0 for all the contexts that I create.

Can someone please help me with this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the PyOpenCL documentation, [Context](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime.html?highlight=get_devices#pyopencl.Context) takes a list of devices, not a specific device.

If you change your context creation code to this:

```
platform = cl.get_platforms()
my_gpu_devices = platform[0].get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.GPU)
ctx = cl.Context(devices=my_gpu_devices)
```

It should work.  If you really want to limit the choice to only one device, you can manipulate the `my_gpu_devices` list, for instance:

```
my_gpu_devices = [platform[0].get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.GPU)[0]]
```

Comment: thank you very much. You solved my problem. By the way, This is also working:
platform = cl.get_platforms();  
my_gpu_devices = platform[0].get_devices(cl.device_type.GPU);  
ctx = cl.Context([my_gpu_devices[0]])

Comment: Yash's version works for me too. K. Brafford, I think there's an error in your last code line. Actually I had to change the Context creation to ctx = l.Context(devices=[my_gpu_devices[0]])