# "clGetPlatformIDs failed: PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR" on Windows? How to install driver?

Tags: pyopencl

I am using a microsoft azure notebook to write a PyOpenCL code, and am using windows 10 with Intel i7-4770K CPU processor.

I managed to install PyOpenCL library, but it throws the error "clGetPlatformIDs failed: PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR" when I write the code:

```
cl.create_some_context()
```

I am guessing no context is being found, so I followed the PyOpenCL documentation which says I need to install the CPU OpenCL driver from Intel from this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_CPU_runtime

And this is the most confusing page I have ever come across. I am not sure what exactly I am supposed to download and install here. Could someone please help me out?

This is my code:

```
import pyopencl as cl
ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
```

And it throws this error: LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

I install PyOpenCL using this code:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pyopencl
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular OpenCL doesn't need any special Intel driver. Its packaged with production drivers.
Please show the code inside "create_some_context()". You must be doing a clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR (which requires a device with the cl_khr_icd extension), instead of a regular clGetPlatformIDs. Your device likely doesn't have cl_khr_icd support.
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_icd.html

Comment: Hi, I added the code I used which creates this error. It's a simple enough code and uses create_some_context from the PyOpenCL library which I import

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me after I got the same error message:

`conda install -c conda-forge pocl`

This answer is strongly inspired by the solution provided here:
[Python LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: platform not found khr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990131/python-logicerror-clgetplatformids-failed-platform-not-found-khr)